# Everything is a Photon

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity

If we accept $E=\hbar \omega$, $p=\hbar k$, and $E^2-(pc)^2=(m_0 c^2)^2$, then we find $$(m_0 c^2)^2 = (\hbar \omega)^2-(\hbar kc)^2 = \hbar (\omega^2 - (kc)^2)=0$$i.e. the rest mass of any particle is $0$.  Therefore every particle is a photon.  What is wrong with this?

Comment: You assume the dispersion to be linear $\omega\propto k$, which is clearly not the general case. A free, non-relativistic particle for example behaves as $\omega \propto k^2$

Comment: If you do consider photon a particle with dimensions ([the University of Glasgow discovered photon to have orbital angular spin](http://www.gla.ac.uk/schools/physics/research/groups/optics/research/orbitalangularmomentum/)), you could try to think of other elementary particles as a photon with added (a number of) real spins that would make your concept worth of serious consideration.

Comment: @nephente That makes sense because $\omega\propto E \propto p^2 \propto k^2$, but how do you reconcile it with $v \textrm{ (const) } = \dfrac{\lambda}{T}=\dfrac{\omega}{k}$?

Answer (score 4):

For a matter wave, it is better to use the variable $v$ for the speed of the matter wave. Then $\omega=k v$, or $\omega=|k|v$. The equation then has a factor of $(kv)^2-(kc)^2$ which does not have to be zero.

Regardless, we shouldn't expect $E^2-(pc)^2=(mc^2)^2$ to be satisfied, because the relation $E=\hbar \omega=\hbar k v$ gives a finite energy when the speed is equal to the speed of light. It's not valid for relativistic speeds.

Comment: How is $E=\hbar \omega$ altered for relativistic speeds?

Comment: @JoshuaMeyers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave gives that $p=\hbar k$ and $E=\hbar \omega$ still hold, but instead of $E=p^2/(2m)$, we have $E=p c^2/v$. So $\hbar\omega=\hbar k c^2/v$. $E^2-(pc)^2=(mc^2)^2$ then simplifies to $(\hbar k)^2=(\gamma m c^2)^2=p^2$. So we just get $(\hbar k)^2=p^2$ again.

Answer (score -1):

In special relativity, $(ck_x, ck_2, ck_3, \omega)$ is a $4$-vector, so $\omega=kc$ does not hold in general.  Instead, $\omega^2-(ck)^2$ is a scalar invariant.  We can find the value of this invariant with the equation in the OP: $$\omega^2-(ck)^2=\frac{(m_0 c^2)^2}{\hbar}$$

However, I think there is more to the story.